# if/else condition not respected in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code in my app.js and when the submit button is pressed, it will send a bunch of information collected from a form to my express server. However, it is supposed to do some checking before and if the conditions are not fulfilled, it will not send that information to the server, instead, it will show me a prompt with a list of fields that are required but left empty.

But my app.js sends the information to my express server whether there is an empty field or not and I can't figure out why. There is no error message, the only error message is a `post 404` not found which means my app.js sent the information to the server without checking the if/else condition and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

if it helps, I am using jQuery instead of DOM manipulation and also uses the jQuery ajax function for posting to my express server. The posting part is fine, the if/else is not.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35524386/javascript-else-if-condition-not-working), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999410/javascript-if-else-condition-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922974/if-else-condition-javascript). But none of those seems to be able to answer my question.

app.js

```
$('#submitBtn').on("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let rackId = $("#umbrella_id").val();
    let umbrellaCount = $('#umbrella_count').val();
    let siteStatus = $('#site_status').val();
    let servicesRendered = $('#services_rendered').val();
    let afterServiceStatus = $('#aft_service_status').val();
    let remarks = $('#remarksTextarea').val();

    if (!remarks) {
        remarks = "Nil";
    }

    const fields = {
        "Umbrella Count": umbrellaCount,
        "Site Status": siteStatus,
        "Services Rendered": servicesRendered,
        "After Service Status": afterServiceStatus
    }
    
    var emptyFields = [];
    Object.keys(fields).forEach((key) => {
        console.log(key)
        if (fields[key] === "" || fields[key] === null) {
            emptyFields.push(key);
        }
    });
        
    
    if (!emptyFields.length) {
        $.post(`/submit/${rackId}/${umbrellaCount}/${siteStatus}/${servicesRendered}/${afterServiceStatus}/${remarks}`)
        loadScreen(false);
    } else {
        // Show the prompt
        for (x in emptyFields) {
            // Append the name of fields that are empty to the prompt
            $('#populateEmptyFields').append(emptyFields[x]);
        }
        $('#emptyFieldWarning').removeClass('position-relative').addClass('position-absolute');
        $('#emptyFieldWarning').prop('hidden', false);
        $('#emptyFieldWarning').show();
        $('#warningDialog').prop('hidden', false);
        $('#warningDialog').show();        
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Well have you checked what `emptyFields` contains, with `console.log(emptyFields)`?

Comment: `if (!emptyFields.length) { $.post(/* ... */) }` so, this executes only if `emptyFields.length` is `0`. Is that correct?

Comment: console.log(emptyFields) is empty. `[]`
What's going on?

Comment: You check for `""` and `null` but not `undefined`.

Comment: If the array is empty then the if condition is working correctly (no surprise there.) The problem is then earlier in the code. You need to do more basic debugging, e.g. `console.log(fields)` to confirm that it contains what you expect, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery Documentation of [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) (emphasis added)

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty collection, it returns **undefined**.

You do not check for `undefined`, you check for empty string or `null`.

```
if (fields[key] === "" || fields[key] === undefined) {
  emptyFields.push(key);
}
```

Here is a stripped down version with the `undefined` fix, a value with `""` and a value with `undefined`

```js
let umbrellaCount = "1"
let siteStatus = ""
let servicesRendered = "1"
let afterServiceStatus = undefined

const fields = {
  "Umbrella Count": umbrellaCount,
  "Site Status": siteStatus,
  "Services Rendered": servicesRendered,
  "After Service Status": afterServiceStatus
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2))

var emptyFields = [];
Object.keys(fields).forEach((key) => {
  if (fields[key] === "" || fields[key] === undefined) {
    emptyFields.push(key);
  }
});

console.log(emptyFields)

if (!emptyFields.length) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Copied and paste your codes to my codes, the emptyFields array is still empty.

Comment: Do any of the fields match "", null, or undefined? This is definitely a problem in your code, and there may be something else going on that we cannot know without more information.

Comment: Have you tried something like `console.log(JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2))`? That would help spot something like a `" "` value

Comment: @TengBangWei I've added code with some values that do trigger the "false" path of the `if`/`else`, and it does work correctly.

Comment: Thank you @crashmstr, it worked now. Not sure what happened though. It's late in Asia now. So I will study the codes tomorrow morning and update this thread subsequently.